# select method fails in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, dom

When the user enters some "junk" in input field 1, the blur event triggers a function to notify them of the error and then `select()`'s the field triggering the error.  This works fine in IE and Safari but Firefox and Chrome skip right over the `select()`.  If I use FireBug to step through the code, it works as designed.

Here is a sample of the code:

```js
function checkForJunk(fld) {
  if (fld.value == 'junk') {
    alert('please take out the junk');
    fld.select();
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="junk" action="junk.htm" method="post">
  Input1:
  <input type="text" name="morejunk" value="" onBlur="checkForJunk(this);" />
  <br>
  Input2:
  <input type="text" name="evenMorejunk" value="" onBlur="checkForJunk(this);" />
</form>
```

Comment: Have you ever tried fld.focus() ?

Comment: Either you can't refocus the element during the blur event or, since you are focusing another element, that focus event happens after `select()`. If you put the `select()` call in a  `setTimeout`, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me on chrome when I put the select in a setTimeout

```
setTimeout(function() {
       fld.select(); 
}, 1);
```